# getting."flexslider is not a function" only sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

I get the following error every now and then when I try to run flexslider on my website:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function

I've searched all the similar questions and tried the solutions but nothing worked. jQuery is only loaded once and it is loaded before flexslider. I get this error **only sometimes** (maybe once every 10 tries). It's boggling my mind. Here is what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lightbox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/flexslider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Nunito|Roboto:100" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
...html stuff...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        slideshow: false,
        directionNav: true,
        controlNav: false,
        startAt: 0,
        touch: true,
        prevText: "",
        nextText: ""
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think if you use ready function it gona work.

try something like this

```
$('.flexslider').ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            slideshow: false,
            directionNav: true,
            controlNav: false,
            startAt: 0,
            touch: true,
            prevText: "",
            nextText: ""
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Won't .ready() only run when that specific element is loaded on the page, not the javascript function itself?